# ZXing Aztec Barcode UTF-8

Tags: c#, utf-8, zxing

I try to create a Aztec Barcode with special letter like 'ä'.
I tried to activate UTF-8 but the barcode still only contains hex.
Somebody knows whats wrong?

```
var writer = new BarcodeWriter
{
    Format = BarcodeFormat.AZTEC,
    Options = new AztecEncodingOptions
    {
        Height = Height,
        Width = Width,
    }
};

//Hashtable hints = new Hashtable();
//writer.Options.Hints.Add(EncodeHintType.CHARACTER_SET, "utf-8");

//KeyValuePair<EncodeHintType, object> valuePair = new KeyValuePair<EncodeHintType, object>(EncodeHintType.CHARACTER_SET, "UTF-8");                
//writer.Options.Hints.Add(valuePair);

writer.Options.Hints.Add(EncodeHintType.DISABLE_ECI, true);
writer.Options.Hints.Add(EncodeHintType.CHARACTER_SET, "UTF-8");

var bitmap = writer.Write(value);
Bitmap img = new Bitmap(bitmap);
```

[Barcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baflp.jpg)

Thank you!

Comment: That is `Encoding` in your code? It can't be the [System.Text.Encoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding?view=netcore-3.1) class.

Comment: Oh yes. Its a param. I tried "UTF-8" also...i edited the code..

Comment: The default character set ISO8859-1 for Aztec codes can represent the character ä. Why did you try UTF-8?

Comment: the first try was without utf-8. the character ä was not represented.

Comment: I can't believe that. I tried your content with the WinForm demo application of zxing.net and it works without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Was "abcanfuiwefbieäääää" your input?
The result bitmap gives "abcanfuiwefbieÃ¤Ã¤Ã¤Ã¤Ã¤" which is UTF-8 encoding of "abcanfuiwefbieäääää" seen as latin1.

What happens here is the encoder recognizes and handles well character set hint, but the decoder ignores it and interprets it as latin1. Thus, to get your original text, you'll need to convert latin1 to UTF8 yourself.

Comment: Yes my content should be "abcanfuiwefbieäääää". The Problem is that i need to show the 'ä'. When or where i have do convert latin1 to UTF8?

Comment: You need to convert the result text. E.g. `com.google.zxing.Result result = reader.decode(...);  String finalText = new String(result.getText(), "ISO-8859-1").getBytes("UTF-8");`